# Bazel test does not work with mingw-gcc . How should I debug this?

Tags: c++, bazel, googletest, build-tools

I'm following this really basic example here to setup gtest with bazel:

http://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-bazel.html

it works fine (and tests pass) but I would like to use mingw gcc compiler with this (not the default mysys). Upon running this I get a single test failed, with no output displayed.

I can easily build or run files using this compiler. My output is below ( if it helps at all ):

```
C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\testProj>bazel test --test_output=all //:hello_test --verbose_failures
DEBUG: Rule 'com_google_googletest' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments sha256 = "5cf189eb6847b4f8fc603a3ffff3b0771c08eec7dd4bd961bfd45477dd13eb73"
DEBUG: Repository com_google_googletest instantiated at:
  C:/users/<user>/desktop/testproj/WORKSPACE:3:13: in <toplevel>
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  C:/users/<user>/_bazel_<user>/x2p76flj/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:355:31: in <toplevel>
INFO: Analyzed target //:hello_test (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
FAIL: //:hello_test (see C:/users/<user>/_bazel_<user>/x2p76flj/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/testlogs/hello_test/test.log)
INFO: From Testing //:hello_test:
==================== Test output for //:hello_test:
================================================================================
Target //:hello_test up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/hello_test.exe
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.269s, Critical Path: 0.08s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 local.
INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
//:hello_test                                                            FAILED in 0.0s
  C:/users/<user>/_bazel_<user>/x2p76flj/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/testlogs/hello_test/test.log

INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
```

The log file is also empty, and shows what the stdout here shows

Comment: My guess would be the mingw dlls aren't on your path so the test exe fails to launch

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks for the response :D they should be, I mean ive added all the mingw binaries to the system path and they sit alongside the dlls , moreover i'd expect bazel run <some target> to fail due to this same reason , which it doesn't.



Just to be double sure I just copied across all the mingw dll's into the same directory as the binary and same issue. Any other thoughts here?

Comment: @AlanBirtles you were totally right, sorry this is stupid, all I needed was to add `linkopts=["-static"],` not sure why, and not sure why the dynamic linking didn't work, but happy this is resolved now

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into this issue in future, you simply need to add `linkopts=["-static"],` to your cc_test rule. Not sure why it wasn't correctly dynamically linking

Comment: This did not solve it for me unfortunately :(

Comment: @Zoom something I have found to help in the past is to inspect the return code you are actually getting after running the executable, just to get an understanding of why it is failing after running. There should be a command on windows for returning the last exit code

Comment: Can also try double check what env I had to set for bazel mingw after initially installing later if you think that would help . I remember that was a pain too and poorly documented

Comment: Thanks for helping. I don't know the return code for now but I posted a question with what Bazel says: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75367757/bazel-cant-find-g-despite-both-msys2-and-native-shell-supporting-it Am I supposed to check the return code for this bazel command or the return code for running gcc/g++ inside Bazel? I.e. something like "echo ... gcc ..."?

Comment: On windows that should be as simple as `echo %errorlevel%` (after the bazel run/bazel test)
and you can check online what that specific code means (confirm or deny if its DLL related for example)

Its late here and can try check your specific error more tomorrow :)