# Bazel can't find g++ despite both MSYS2 and native shell supporting it

Tags: g++, bazel, msys2

I have installed Bazel through Chocolatey on Windows and MSYS2 to have access to bash.exe.

A script I am trying to build uses g++ which I installed through pacman in MSYS2 and also added to PATH. I am able to run `g++ --version` in both the MSYS2 shell and my native Powershell.

But somehow it seems as if MSYS2 can't run g++ when I am running it through Bazel.

```
C:/<censored>> bazel build //kernels:rasterize_triangles_kernel
INFO: Analyzed target //kernels:rasterize_triangles_kernel (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
ERROR: C:/<censored>/kernels/BUILD:20:8: Executing genrule //kernels:rasterize_triangles_kernel failed: (Exit 127): bash.exe failed: error executing command (from target //kernels:rasterize_triangles_kernel) C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe -c ... (remaining 1 argument skipped)
/usr/bin/bash: line 1: g++: command not found
Target //kernels:rasterize_triangles_kernel failed to build                                                                                                                                                                                 
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.                                                                                                                                                                      
INFO: Elapsed time: 4.883s, Critical Path: 4.80s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 internal.                                                                                                                                                                                                              
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Comment: Coming from other post :) sorry just saw your issue and it does seem to be unrelated to my one which was more about testing. This indeed is likely related to some environment variable based problem, I'm going to give you some environment variables to set In comment below you can try:

Comment: Interestingly could not reproduce your issues by modifying my local environment, but I remember needing it at one point. You can try these

Add as env variables:

BAZEL_SH=C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe
CC=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe

I believe those first 2 were important

BAZEL_VC=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC

Might not be needed ^^ but I did try using visual studio at one point (default compiler bazel uses on windows)

Add to path:

C:\msys64\mingw64\bin
C:\msys64\usr\bin

<continues below>

Comment: Importantly , in the root of your project (or next to the WORKSPACE file) create a `.bazelrc` file and importantly add these 2 separate lines:

build --compiler=mingw-gcc
build --enable_runfiles

Might not need enable_runfiles, but it's important if you want to work with them from recollection (on windows OS).

Sorry none of this formatted as nicely as I would have liked but I hope its clear what still needs to be added :) Let me know how it goes

Comment: I set all of these and had to restart my PC multiple times. Eventually it worked but I have no idea what actually made it work. My thesis is that using WSL is the best option to get around this issue altogether.

Comment: Interesting, glad you got it working - hopefully it can serve to help others in future too